# How do I add TFS as a Source control plug in to SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 options, under source control the only available options "out of the box" are Microsoft Visual SourceSafe, and... (wait for it) ...Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (internet).

Since I do have VSTS 2008 installed, with the TFS client of course, I find it odd that SSMS Express doesn't include support for it, especially with the 2008 version.

Yeah, I know I can do all of what I (typically) do in SSMS Express from within VSTS and call it a day.  However, it is a bit more involved than that and the tool of choice in some of the scenarios I am contemplating is the SSMS 2008 Express.

Is this an Express vs. full version thing?  Or is it altogether not supported?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to install this [provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=FAEB7636-644E-451A-90D4-7947217DA0E7&displaylang=en).

> The Visual Studio Team System 2008
>   Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider
>   enables integrated use of Team
>   Foundation Version Control with
>   products that do not support Team
>   Explorer integration.

This does include SSMS

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2010, here's a link: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6

For Visual Studio 2012 the link is
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3c7b6813-2617-4d5f-9a1d-5ad980cab5d2

Comment: Anyone know if there's a "Visual Studio Team System 2012 Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider" available?